# how to disable user logoff from remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, logoff

I need to disable log off function for terminal services users.
Disconnect option only will be acceptable.
Is any script to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work...

There are two group policy settings you can make...  Or you can use the local policy editor.

They are listed in this link:

http://www.hackersorigin.com/disable-a-user-from-logging-off-windows/?mobile=1

```
User Configuration->Administrative Templates->System->Ctrl+Alt+Del Options.
On the right, Enable this setting “Remove Logoff“.
```

and...

```
User Configuration->Administrative Templates->Start Menu and Taskbar.
On the right, Enable this setting “Remove Logoff on the Start Menu“.
```

Comment: just for info, this doesn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: The answer given by Matt is not working on Windows 7