# How to hide 'Shut down' button from an AD group assigned in local Administrators group (Windows Server)?

Tags: windows, active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012

Basically I need to grant a group full local administrative permissions but hide or disable the shutdown button for them in the start menu.

We have Windows servers from 2008 to 2012.

I did my research, however my AD counterpart is stating it is not possible to implement it.

Comment: sooo... did you research something? the first google entry will get you the solution if you google it correctly.

Comment: Hello, I did my research, however my AD counterpart is stating it is not possible to implement it.

Comment: @kaloyan i'd say it's possible to disable or enable the shutdown button, but they can't just "switch" this in a session. they are able to change it and on next logon the change takes effect

Comment: I want to hide it in order to avoid incidents, not to forbid them from shutting the servers down.

Comment: check this. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/ instead of local policy you're doing it on GPO. should be similar.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/579011/118258

Comment: @HopelessN00b, this ways is stating who can see the power button, I need a way to state only who can't.

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory policy "User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Start Menu and Taskbar: Remove and prevent access to the Shut Down command" can state who can't see the Shut down and restart buttons.